# Что более строже dkim=all или dkim=discardable и расскажите более подробнее об этом

Tags: email, dkim

Везде написано одно и тоже!

```
Значений dkim= может быть три:
    all — Все письма должны быть подписаны
    discardable — Не подписанные письма не должны приниматься
    unknown — Аналогично отсутствию записи
```

Мне нужен самый строгий вариант, чтобы И все письма подписывались, И все не подписанные письма отвергались.
Но исходя из этих определений, на сколько я понял, я то ли выбрать должен одно из этого, то ли я должен указать их оба.

Comment: Ни одно из значений нельзя использовать, потому что ADSP объявлен устаревшим ещё в 2013-м

Comment: А вместо ADSP вроде как есть DMARC

Comment: @andreymal То есть если у меня есть запись `_dmarc TXT v=DMARC1; p=reject` то этого (для Google) достаточно?

А `_adsp._domainkey` Можно вообще удалить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ADSP** уже давно устарел и его заменил **DMARC** с вполне очевидным синтаксисом.

```
v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=reject; ruf=mailto:postmaster@example.com; fo=1
```